# Laravel correct way to create a collection and access it in the views

Tags: laravel-5.4

I'm using laravel for this project

this is how I make the collection and pass it in the views

```
public function Add_Student()
{
    $selection = collect([
                          'gender' => ['Male', 'Female'],
                          'yearlevel' => ['1st','2nd','3rd','4th']
                         ]);

    return view('User.content.Add_student')->with('selection',$selection);
}
```

now, I included the view that I want and pass the collection that was sent from the server to the view.

```
@include('pieces.dropdown_button', ['Label' => 'Gender', 'name' => 'Course', 'selection' => $selection])
```

this is the view that was included.

```
      <select>
        <option selected="selected">Select {{ $Label }}</option>

        @foreach($selection['gender'] as $options)

          <option>{{ $options }}</option>

        @endforeach

      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it :)

I NOW know that in

```
    @foreach($selection['gender'] as $options)

      <option>{{ $options }}</option>

    @endforeach
```

$selection will return both

`gender` and `yearlevel` with their datas as an array

now because it returned both you need to select a specific array in the selection whether it would be 
`$selection['gender']` or `$selection['yearlevel']`

now that you've specified the array that you want

loop through that array using `@foreach($selection['gender'] as $options)`

the code above is now for each `gender` in `$selection`

and it puts the value of the current `gender` in the variable `$options`